# Cascading Context Menu in Registry Editor

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu

Following [a guide](https://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menus-for-your-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/), I've been trying to create a cascading menu as a new item in the context menu of a directory.

The item appears in the context menu just fine, however it doesn't open up to list each item as it should and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

[image]

The parent item:

[image: Parent item]

Sub Item:

[image: Sub item]

Sub item command:

[image: Sub item command]

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did a little more digging and found that this isn't the way to do it, despite the guide stating otherwise.

After reading [this article](https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html) I found that `SubCommands` needs to be empty, and then you can add everything as grandchildren.

[image: registry]
[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for this, and for the link to the blog. Had pretty much everything I needed to fix my own implementation having floundered around on a number of other guides and SO posts on this topic!